# How to catch XML parse error in JQuery or prevent XML parsing if status code is 401

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery's ajax method to make cross site requests to a third party system, over which I have no control of the headers or response. When my user is authenticated the server responds with 200's and well formed JSON. When my user is not authenticated the server responds with a 401 and a non JSON string in the body.

Because the response body for 401's is not JSON, jQuery is generating a XML Parsing Error. I'd like to deal with with this error gracefully, rather than having it dumped to the console.

I've tried set the `error` method in the ajax setting object, to handle the 401, but I'm still getting parsing error.

I've also tried wrapping the jQuery ajax call within a `try` `catch` block, but I'm not having any luck in intercepting the parsing error and dealing with it gracefully.

Comment: so you tried .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { // parse your error how you will })

Comment: @Keith thanks for the suggestion, but all it gives me is the 401, not the parse error, which still makes its way to the console.